# How to use widget kartik select2 with ajax & templates in yii2

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

I want to display more than 1 information when searching, so I use select2 ajax & templates. It use json. I change the url and I make function on my controller. But I have a problem. It can not show anything. What's the problem? This is my code:
**view**

```
$formatJs = <<< 'JS'
 var formatProduct = function (product) {
   if (product.loading) {
    return product.text;
   }
 var markup =
    '<div class="row">' + 
      '<div class="col-sm-5">' +
        '<b style="margin-left:5px">' + product.name + '</b>' + 
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-code-fork"></i> ' + product.ean_no + '</div>' +
      '<div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> ' + product.desc + '</div>' +
    '</div>';
    return '<div style="overflow:hidden;">' + markup + '</div>';
  };
  var formatProductSelection = function (product) {
    return product.name || product.text;
  }
JS;

// Register the formatting script
$this->registerJs($formatJs, \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD);

// script to parse the results into the format expected by Select2
$resultsJs = <<< JS
    function (data, params) {
       params.page = params.page || 1;
        return {
            // Change `data.items` to `data.results`.
            // `results` is the key that you have been selected on
            // `actionJsonlist`.
            results: data.results
        };
    }
JS;
```

**Select2**

```
echo Select2::widget([
        'name' => 'kv-repo-template',
        'value' => '14719648',
        'initValueText' => 'kartik-v/yii2-widgets',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Search for a repo ...'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true,
            'minimumInputLength' => 1,
            'ajax' => [
                'url' => Url::to(['/bom/product/productlist']),
                'dataType' => 'json',
                'delay' => 250,
                'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term, page: params.page}; }'),
                'processResults' => new JsExpression($resultsJs),
                'cache' => true
            ],
            'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
            'templateResult' => new JsExpression('formatProduct'),
            'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('formatProductSelection'),
        ],
    ]);
```

**controller**

```
public function actionProductlist($search = NULL, $code = NULL)
{
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $clean['more'] = false;

    $query = new \yii\db\Query;
    if(!is_Null($search))
    {
        $mainQuery = $query->select('code, name, description, volume')
                           ->from('product');
        $command = $mainQuery->createCommand();
        $rows = $command->queryAll();
        $clean['results'] = array_values($rows);
    }
    else
    {
        if(!is_null($code))
        {
            $clean['results'] = ['ean_no'=> $code, 'name' => Product::find($code)->nama,
                'description' => Product::find($code)->description, 'volume' => Product::find($code)->volume];
        }else
        {
            $clean['results'] = ['ean_no' => 123, 'name' => 'None found', 'description' => 'None found', 'volume' => 'None found'];
        }
    }
    echo \yii\helpers\Json::encode($clean);
    exit();
}
```

on mozilla when i open the inspect element console. there is an error message like this :

TypeError: data.slice is not a function
S2

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

```
'processResults' => new JsExpression($resultsJs),
```

Comment: still does not appear in the dropdown

Comment: I think Select2 expects id and text values, so in the array you have to change ean_no key to id, name to text

Comment: What do you mean? should not matter instead if without id?

Comment: As stated here https://select2.org/data-sources/formats 
 Select2 expects a very specific data format!
So you need id and text property. Or you need to process result and convert properties. But I think it's better way to change keys in your output array

Comment: i think my problem in controller

Comment: Yes, the problem is in your controller. You should return array in format that Select2 expects 'id'=>'key', 'text'=>'value'